# How to print out the output of "tar" execution until it finishes using telnetlib?

Tags: python, telnet, tar, telnetlib

I tried to print out as 'tar' command extracts files, but I can't print out the output of the progress.

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("x.x.x.x")

tn.write("tar -xvf a.tar")
print tn.read_until("#")
time.sleep(1800)
```

Above code prints out the all output after execution, and need to wait although the `tar` finishes less than 1800 secs.

Another try is

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("x.x.x.x")

tn.write("tar -xvf a.tar")
print tn.read_eager()

print tn.read_all()
```

This code doesn't print the output while executing `tar`. Would you give me any idea how to print out while `tar` is running, and return as soon as it finishes `tar` execution without waiting?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like it has something to do with buffering

Comment: The `time.sleep(1800)` doesn't happen until after the `read_until` has finished, so it isn't doing you any good whatsoever. What are you _trying_ to do with that? If we knew that, we might be able to explain how to do it, rather than trying to guess based on what you attempted. (See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more, and the help may be helpful as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what was your problem with the 1st script...  Anyways can you try this?

```
tn.write("tar -xvf a.tar")
while True:
    resp = tn.read_until("#", 1.0)
    if 0 == len(resp): break
    print resp
print "done"
```

The loop waits for the telnet connection to become silent by specifying the timeout parameter `1.0`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to get answered. Currently, I'm using curl http://x.x.x.x/a.tar | tar -xf and wanted to know the output from telnet session. Appreciate!!